# AFNetworking: GET with query string

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I´m trying to access a web service from my iOS application. In the documentation it says that I should use a query string to pass the parameters but I´m not sure on how to use this.

I using the AFNetworking framework. Made a POST request earlier and it worked just fine, but not sure on how to write and pass a query string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'query string' is produced by AFNetworking.  Just use the getPath:parameter:... method and provide the parameter dictionary.  Make sure the dictionary has a key for each of the query names required by the web service.

For example:

```
[client getPath: @"transactions"
     parameters: @{ @"api_key" : ksomeAPIKey,
                    @"user_id" : user_id }
     ...]
```

will be converted, by AFNetworking, to:

```
 GET <baseURL>/transactions?api_key=...&user_id=...
```

Comment: I can´t try this yet but I´m sure it will work, thanks a lot GoZoner, great answer.

Comment: If you're using a `AFHTTPClient` then you might want to explicitly set  its `parameterEncoding = AFFormURLParameterEncoding`;